# Dropdown List with different display name and values

Tags: infopath, dropdown

When I create a dropdown list I'd like to have different names when choosing an option than their actual values.

For example, when I click on the drop down list I get the following options:

- Direct Federal Tax Law
- Cantonal Tax Law

When I then choose one it shouldn't insert the whole name in the field but rather only the abbreviation. So when I choose Cantonal Tax Law it should insert CTL into the field.

How can I specify this?

In advance many many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves your purpose, but you can use display templates to modify the way text is displayed in the view. 
See below article,

http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2012/js-link-for-sharepoint-2013-web-partsa-quick-functional-primer/

Look at example 3 in the article and see if that solves your issue.
It only changes the data that is displayed. You will see the original value when you edit the form.

You can also use display templates to modify the forms.
See below article for customizing the display form using display templates,

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/01/customize-list-form-fields-in-display-form-dispform-aspx-using-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013-2/

Comment: The problem with saving the way you mentioned in the original question is, SharePoint will then create a new choice for you(for example, CTL) and display that new value when you open the display/edit form instead of the actual value(Cantonal Tax Law)